# can i convert gui program into .exe file?

Tags: user-interface, matlab, exe

Hye all.. I am just asking.. if there any possibilities to convert my gui program into .exe file? How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can using the [MATLAB Compiler](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/). There are some [Limitations and Restrictions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/compiler/br2cqa0-1.html) but I haven't encountered a show stopper yet. From a simplified point of view , the MATLAB Compiler creates p-code of your m-files, that runs on the 'MATLAB Compiler Runtime'. The 'MATLAB Compiler Runtime' is like an ordinary MATLAB installation, but **missing** the **compiler**.

Comment: owh.. so i have to use the complier.. is this some sort a converter software? Like flv into mp3?

Comment: @raymond: It is more like 'javac' and 'java' in the Java world. The compiler ('javac') creates byte code that runs ('java') on the runtime engine.

Answer (score 0):

The [MATLAB Compiler](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/) allows you to bundle your GUI with the [MATLAB Compiler Runtime](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/compiler/f12-999353.html) (an engine that provides all of MATLAB's computing) into a distributable without license restrictions. It's not cheap, however.

Comment: Nothing ever is with MATLAB. Sheesh.